# Are there some way to debug a gradle webapp from Netbeans?

Tags: debugging, tomcat, netbeans, gradle

How can I use gradle to debug Tomcat from Netbeans? 
I tried with the second solution from: https://www.timroes.de/2014/06/22/using-gradle-to-debug-tomcat/ but I am getting this error while trying to run *gradle tomcatDebug*:

> Could not fetch model of type ‘BuildEnvironment’ using Gradle
>   distribution
>   ‘https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.3-all.zip’.